# How to use strcmp in if statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have to compare two string and process based on the result of strcmp in my sql.

sample:

```
Set @login='USC00010';
set @user='USC00010';
select STRCMP(@login,@user);//returns 0
if(STRCMP(@login,@user)= 0)
THEN
//process1
else
//process2
end if;
```

and the above code throws You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if(STRCMP(@login,@user)= 0)

Actual requirement:

```
if(//matches)
begin
if exists(select X from X ) 
begin
if exists(select x from x where y=a)
begin 
update x                   
end
end
else//doesn't match
begin 
//process2                      
end
```

Comment: Is this a stored proceedure?

Comment: yes,it's a stored procedure

Comment: Then please show the complete code or at least a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question has been edited with requirement.

Comment: Hi @johnsigeorge did you find the solution for this? I'm facing the same issue :/

Answer (score 1):

```
Set @login='USC00010';
set @user='USC00010';
select if(STRCMP(@login,@user)= 0,"match","no-match") as str_compare
```

Comment: I have tried this too.But my problem is based to match or nomatch ,i have a a process of select and update(in process1)